# Ruby on Rails Condition Broken

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I have Ruby on Rails 2.3.x. I have a database for a learning management system.

Users are given a user ID, and take quizzes. If a user takes any number of quizzes, I want the average score to display. The score is listed in the `quiz_results` table as a float between 0 and 1, hence the `* 100` and `.round`, with a `user_id` row as well. But if a user hasn't taken any quizzes, I want `"No quizzes taken"` to appear.

Here's the code:

```
-if QuizResult.find_by_user_id(@user_id).present?
    ="#{(QuizResult.average('score', :conditions => 'user_id = #{@user.id}') * 100).round}%"
-else
    %em No quizzes taken
```

The problem is that no matter what, even if there is a `quiz_results` entry, the `"No quizzes taken"` still appears.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try to replace with `if QuizResult.find_by_user_id(@user_id)`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, no change.

Comment: try `if QuizResult.find_by_user_id(@user_id).any?`

Comment: Gives me an error: "ActionView::TemplateError (undefined method `any?' for nil:NilClass)"  :(

Comment: ok but if `QuizResult.find_by_user_id(@user_id)` is `nil`, then the condition `if QuizResult.find_by_user_id(@user_id)` should work... (both `false` and `nil` are `false` conditions in Ruby)

Comment: I know, right? Hence my quandary.

Comment: actually, the issue is the condition is always `false`, are you really sure there are entries matching your `@user_id`?

Comment: Positive. Just double-checked.

Comment: what is the value of `@user_id`?

Comment: 3907. The is also one 'score' = 0.1.

Comment: so Rails wan't find it? weird... why do you have both `@user_id` and `@user.id` in your code?

Comment: Don't really know. But as per answer below, switching to user.id in the -if line doesn't change the results.

Answer (score 0):

You're testing whether:

```
QuizResult.find_by_user_id(@user_id)
```

exists, but I suspect you meant:

```
QuizResult.find_by_user_id(@user.id)
```

Comment: Thanks. No change in behavior. Still just shows "No quizzes taken."