# RoR: Condition Always False - Why?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I am working in Rails 2.3.x on a learning management system. Here's my code:

```
-@users.each do |user|
    %tr
        %td
            =link_to h(user.name), :action => :show_user, :id => user.id
        %td="#{h user.grade_level}"
        -if QuizResult.find_by_user_id(@user_id).present?
            ="#{(QuizResult.average('score', :conditions => 'user_id = #{@user.id}') * 100).round}%"
        -else
            %em No quizzes taken
```

My `quiz_results` table has columns for `user_id` and `score`, among others. I have a record with a `user_id` (3907) and `result` (0.1), and two users I'm looking at with no records in the `quiz_results` table.

The display says `"No quizzes taken"` for all three, which leads me to believe that this line is false no matter what:

```
-if QuizResult.find_by_user_id(@user_id).present?
```

Any ideas how to fix?

Comment: Can you rephrase your question with some more details?

Comment: I think you have two questions. Better to state two questions by a seperator.

Comment: Better to not ask two questions at all on Stack Overflow. One question per question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby on Rails Condition Broken](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12197784/ruby-on-rails-condition-broken)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `@user_id` to `user.id` in the `if` statement and `@user.id` to `user.id`. Also change the single quotations to double quotations or using string interpolation won't work.

Comment: Gives me an error: ActionView::TemplateError (undefined local variable or method `user_id' for #<ActionView::Base:0x6bc1426faad0>) on line #19 of app/views/manage_users/show_all_users.haml:

Comment: With double quotes I get: ActionView::TemplateError (undefined method `*' for nil:NilClass) on line #20 of app/views/manage_users/show_all_users.haml:
17:                 =link_to h(user.name), :action => :show_user, :id => user.id
18:             %td="#{h user.grade_level}"
19:             -if QuizResult.find_by_user_id(user.id).present?
20:                 %td="#{(QuizResult.average('score', :conditions => "user_id = #{@user.id}") * 100).round}%"
21:             -else
22:                 %td
23:                     %em No quizzes taken

Comment: Did you change @user_id for user.id as well as @user.id?

Comment: Scratch that. :) Fixed it so the output line was a constant, and it functions as it should. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to change `@user.id` to `user.id`.

Answer (score 0):

As the answer to second part of your question, I think you can't have a nested evaluated string (the nested `#{}`). You need to compute the results first, then evaluate and output it in HAML:

```
-averge = QuizResult.average('score', :conditions => 'user_id = #{@user.id}') * 100).round
="#{average}%"
```

Comment: Thanks. Where do I put the average = line? RoR newbie...sorry...and thanks. :)

Comment: Got it:      -average = (QuizResult.average('score', :conditions => "user_id = #{user.id}") * 100).round  
    %td="#{average}%"  Thanks!!!!